# Placing image and text on same line in a span

Tags: html, css

Having some trouble with this.

I followed this: [CSS align images and text on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596821/css-align-images-and-text-on-same-line) and a few other sources and not a whole lot of luck.

With the link above, it suggests adding `float:left;clear:left;` as a solution. It partially works, but it pushes the icons to the far corner instead of keeping it to the center.
HTML

```
<div class="parent">
<span class="child"><img class="clipart" src="http://waplasticsurgery.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/test_phone.png">(XXX)-XXX-XXXX</span>
<div id="space"></div>
<span class="child">Email Inquiry</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent{
  width:100%;
  height:76px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  border-radius:12px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:flexbox;
  display:flex;
  text-align:center;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
#space{
  width:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.child{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
  width:200px;
  height:45px;
  line-height:45px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  border:2px solid #8CAAD2;
  border-radius:10px;
}

.clipart{
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5xer7pmp/)

The end goal is to have it vertical and horizontal aligned with the other text.

All tips appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.parent{
  width:100%;
  height:76px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  border-radius:12px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:flexbox;
  display:flex;
  text-align:center;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
#space{
  width:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.child{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
  width:200px;
  height:45px;
  line-height:45px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  border:2px solid #8CAAD2;
  border-radius:10px;
}

.clipart{
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    clear:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<span class="child"><img class="clipart" src="http://i.imgur.com/Cc37OOU.png">(XXX)-XXX-XXXX</span>
<div id="space"></div>
<span class="child"><img class="clipart" src="http://i.imgur.com/IsuHm7W.png">Email Inquiry</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm. For me this it how it appears on my site using that code: http://image.prntscr.com/image/1b7395bf44894919b3044881c1f2aa70.png

Comment: @Travis Try adding this:`.row .col img {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
`

Comment: Thanks so much. I was thinking there was something else causing the issue

Comment: @Travis No problem glad to Help :)

Answer (score 0):

css: `display: inline-block` or `display: inline`

Comment: If you look, the content is float:left;

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/o58vsw68/1/

Use the following CSS and insert a space afet your images in the HTML:

```
.child{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
  width:200px;
  height:45px;
  line-height:45px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  border:2px solid #8CAAD2;
  border-radius:10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.clipart{
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
```