# HTML/CSS: How to get text around image to fit when window is resized?

Tags: html, css, image, text, responsiveness

When the view of my webpage is on a desktop the text next to it displays fine, however, the moment I resize it to a much smaller size, the text appears all cluttered and appears underneath the images or past the footer. Is it possible to make the text around the image display comfortably, maybe having it above the image or so?

HTML/CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/jof0hzhc/15/

```css
html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
}

 
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}

li>a{display:;}
li>a:hover, /*li hover makes the area around the list of text have a block of color around it when you hover over the text*/
li>a:focus{color:red;text-decoration:underline;} /*li focus is when you select the element, the element gets into a focus*/
 
header {
      width: 98%;
      height: 13vh;
     
}

.welcome {
 font-family: courier;
 padding: 30px;
 font-size: 60px;
 color: white;
}

.intro {
 color: white;
 
}

.content {
      width: 94%;
      margin: 4em auto;
      font-size: 20px;
      line-height: 30px;
      text-align: justify;
}

.content h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}


.apphead {
 color: white;
 font-size: 100px;
 font-family: courier;
}

.apptext {
 color:white;
 font-size: 45px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: courier;
 
}

.games {
 margin:0;
 position:relative;
 border:solid white; 
}

.games img {
 position:relative;
 max-width:100%;
 padding: 5px;
 transition: 1s;
 
}
 
.games img:hover {
 transform: scale(1.1);
}

.item img{
 display:block;
}

.box {
 position: absolute;
 color: white;
 display: inline;
 font-size: 17px;

}

/**
 * Footer Styles
 */

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  text-align: center;
  
}

.logo {
      line-height: 60px;
      position: fixed;
      float: left;
      margin: 16px 46px;
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 60px;
   z-index: 1; /*Allows for the navigation bar to stack on top of content and not appear as it overlaps*/
}
 
nav ul {
      line-height: 60px;
      list-style: none;
      background: black;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: right;
      margin: 0;
      padding-right: 40px;
      transition: 1s;
}
 
nav.black ul {
      background: orange;
   opacity: 10;
}
 
nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 16px 40px;;
}
 
nav ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      font-size: 16px;
}
 
.menu-icon {
      line-height: 60px;
      width: 100%;
      background: #000;
      text-align: right;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 15px 24px;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: orange;
      display: none;
}

.activepage { 
 font-size: 25px;
 color: red;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

 
@media(max-width: 786px) {
 
      .logo {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            margin-top: 16px;
      }
 
      nav ul {
            max-height: 0px;
            background: #000;
      }
 
      nav.black ul {
            background: #000;
      }
 
      .showing {
            max-height: 34em;
      }
 
      nav ul li {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 24px;
            text-align: center;
      }
 
      .menu-icon {
            display: block;
      }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Responsive Sticky Navbar</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"> </script>

</head>
<body>
      <div class="wrapper">
            <header>

                  <nav>

                        <div class="menu-icon">
                              <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                        </div>

                        <div class="logo">
                              LOGO
                        </div>

                        <div class="menu">
                              <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                              </ul>
                        </div>
                  </nav>

            </header>
   <div class="slideshow">
    <h2 class="welcome">Heading</h2>
    <div class="blueberry"> <!----Image slider with 4 images---->
     <ul class="slides">
      <li><img src="images/spiderman.jpg" height="600px" /></li> </a>
      <li><img src="images/kh3.jpg" /></li> </a>
      <li><img src="images/galaxy.jpg" /></li> </a>
      <li><img src="images/blue.jpg" /></li> </a>
     </ul>
    </div>

            <div class="content">
                  <p class="intro">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                  </p>
      <p class="intro">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                  </p>
      <p class="intro">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                  </p>
      <p class="intro">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                  </p>
      <p class="intro">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                  </p>
      <p class="intro">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                  </p>
      <p class="intro">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                  </p>
                  
      <p class="apptext">Games
     <div class="games">
      <img src="images/1.png" width="640px" height="250px">
      <p class="box">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
      
     </div>
     <div class="games">
      <img src="images/2.jpg" width="640px" height="250px">
      <p class="box">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="games">
      <img src="images/3.jpg" width="640px" height="250px">
      <p class="box">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="games">
      <img src="images/4.jpg" width="640px" height="250px">
      <p class="box">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="games">
      <img src="images/5.jpg" width="640px" height="250px">
      <p class="box">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="games">
      <img src="images/6.jpg" width="640px" height="250px">
      <p class="box">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
     </div>
            </div>
      </div>

     

</body>


<div class="footer">This footer will always be positioned at the bottom of the page, but <strong>not fixed</strong>.</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are using `position: absolute` and, when the child element has this property, the parent element will ignore its height in order to compute its automatic size. So the height of the element is *uniquely* given by the image. When you resize your browser, the text will dispose on several lines but the height of the div won't change!

To solve this, you have two solutions:

- *Use a fixed height*, if you are sure your text will never exceed that height (it's a bit risky).
- *Use `position: relative` in place of `position: absolute`*. This won't align the text and the image on the same row, but you can use [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596821/css-align-images-and-text-on-same-line) for this problem (and I also added one more now!).