# How to align image and text in one line?

Tags: html, css

I have an image and some text and I want them to be aligned on the same line, but currently the a tag is higher than my text, how can I align them?

here is my html:

```html
<div class="author-name">
    <img class="article-author-img" src="{{ preload(asset('assets/static/images/sarah/person-icon.png')) }}"/> 
    By <a href="https://track.theincrediblemehtod.com" target="_blank">Dexter McBride</a>
</div>
<div class="article-date">
<img src="{{ preload(asset('assets/static/images/sarah/clock-icon.png')) }}" class="article-author-img "/>
```

and my css:

```css
.article-author {
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    color: #494949;
    .author-name {
        font-size: 19px;
        a {
            color: #e80222;
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-family: $fontOpenSansBold;
        }
    }
    .article-date {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .article-author-img {
        padding-right: 10px;
    }
}
```

I tried by applying `vertical-align: middle;` but that did not work.

Comment: duplicate. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596821/css-align-images-and-text-on-same-line

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
.author-name: {
  display: 'flex';
  align-items: 'center',
  justify-content: 'you should choose here something that best suits you'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean aligned on bottom?
You can use flex:

```css
.author-name {
  font-size: 19px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.author-name a {
  color: #e80222;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: $fontOpenSansBold;
}
         
.article-author-img {
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="author-name"> 
<img class="article-author-img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/11/30/14/11/kitty-551554__340.jpg"/>
<span>By <a href="https://track.theincrediblemehtod.com" target="_blank">Dexter McBride</a>
</span>
</div>
```

I changed image as yours was not available :)