# How can I make this text inline with the image

Tags: text, vertical-alignment

I am trying to make this text be lined with this image. Currently the text is below the PayPal image text, but I want them aligned. Any help would be great.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvkIc.jpg)

```
<p><a title="Checkout with PayPal" href="/EPiServer/CMS/Content/,,9/checkout?epieditmode=False"><img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/digitalassets/c/website/marketing/apac/C2/logos-buttons/optimize/logo-center-other-options-white-now-accepting-pp-v8.png" alt="Now accepting PayPal" border="0" /></a>Available in Checkout</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try searching for similar questions? This is a fairly common use scenario.
[How to put img inline with text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201756/how-to-put-img-inline-with-text)
[CSS align images and text on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596821/css-align-images-and-text-on-same-line)

I also think your text does not seem aligned because of the height of your image. You can try cropping it to remove the white space above and below the logo.

[image]

Comment: For some reason, StackOverflow removes "Hello Haseeb" from the beginning of my answer. Curious about the rationale.

Comment: I got the image from https://www.paypal.com/c2/webapps/mpp/logos-buttons, still dosnt seem to work

Comment: @HaseebRahman you can either 
- crop the image to remove the white space below the logo OR 
- add the "padding-bottom" attribute to your text 
to bring it to the same level as the text